# setPadding on ImageView crashes activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, imageview, android-actionbar-compat

I use actionbarcompat to have an actionbar also on pre honeycomp devices.

As there is no space between the home icon and the title of the actionbar, I added this to my activites:

```
// add padding to the right of home item
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(android.R.id.home);
view.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);
```

Actually the second line (setPadding) is causing the crash.

It is working fine on Jelly Bean devices. But I get a Null Pointer exception running this on e.g. Android 2.3 device.

This is the logcat output of the crash:

```
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.GetRichOrDieSmoking/com.GetRichOrDieSmoking.MainScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at com.GetRichOrDieSmoking.MainScreen.onCreate(MainScreen.java:463)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-29 11:44:36.968: E/AndroidRuntime(329):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`android.R.id.home`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html#home) was introduced only in API level 11. So the view could not be created in Android 2.3. Hence in the following line when you try to set padding on the null view you get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thx for that information. Do you have a clue how to get handle to the view on pre honeycomp devices?

Comment: @tobias Define your own id instead of depending on the one supplied by  android. Then use `R.id.home` after importing the package for your own R.java.

Comment: I added the import. And changed to ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.home); But this gives me an error in eclipse stating: "home cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Ah, I realize you're referring to the home icon of actionbarcompat. Sorry, that's not possible by declaring your own id.

Comment: So there is no way to get handle to the view ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't access the home view probably because of the API level .

use a third party library for the action bar in order to support low API levels.

i strongly suggest using the [actionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) .

Comment: I was thinking about actionBarSherlock before, but as Google has provided the actionbarcompat I thought this is the right way to go.

Comment: no it's fine , they even recommended it themselves in one of their google io videos . the actionBarSherlock offers some more flexibility and actually extends the one of google , so why not use it ...